# Find positive constants $C_0$ ,$C_1$ to bound the following inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $0 <\alpha$. Show that there are positive constants $C_0 ,C_1$ so that, for x and
y non-negative we have the inequalities:
$$
C_0(x+y)^{\alpha}\leq(x^\alpha+y^\alpha)\leq C_1(x+y)^{\alpha}
$$

Find $C_1$ is not difficult. But how to find $C_0$?

Comment: Couldn't you just pick $C_0=0$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD $C_0=0$ is not postive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for $\alpha>1$, $f(x)=x^\alpha$ is convex since $f''(x)=\alpha(\alpha-1)x^{\alpha-2}>0$. So by using
$$ f(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})\le\frac{1}{2}(f(x_1)+f(x_2))$$
one has
$$ (\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})^\alpha\le\frac{1}{2}(x_1^\alpha+x_2^\alpha)$$
or
$$ 2^{1-\alpha}(x_1+x_2)^\alpha\le x_1^\alpha+x_2^\alpha. $$
Thus $C_0=2^{\alpha-1}$. For $\alpha\in(0,1)$ one can discuss similarly.

Comment: for $\alpha\in(0,1)$, we have $f(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})\ge\frac{1}{2}(f(x_1)+f(x_2)) \Rightarrow -2^{1−\alpha}(x_1+x_2)^{\alpha}≤x_1^{\alpha}+x_2^{\alpha}$ Since $C_0$ must be positive, so in this inequality we cannot find such $C_0$. In addition, there is a little mistake in the first row : it should be $ x^{\alpha-2}$ instead of $x^{\alpha-1}$

Comment: @Gatsby, That's right.

Answer (score 0):

For $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, note that
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{x}{x+y}\right)^{\alpha} \ge \frac{x}{x+y},
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{y}{x+y}\right)^{\alpha} \ge \frac{y}{x+y}.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
x^{\alpha} + y^{\alpha} \ge (x+y)^{\alpha}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Your proof is also very useful, but I could upvote only one answer, thank you!